# "Square Feet of Space Over Five Floors"

Tags: prepositions

I have a question concerning the meaning of the preposition *over* in this [news article](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/07/05/realestate/sarah-jessica-parker-sells-her-house-for-over-18-million.html):

> The sprawling townhouse has 6,800 square feet of space ***over*** five floors, including the ground level, which opens to a meticulously landscaped tiered garden in the back that can also be viewed from a Juliet balcony on the parlor floor.

I checked this [dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/over) and found definitions 9a and 9b under prepositions *over*:

> 9a:  so as to cover the surface of (something)
>   9b:   in every part of (a place)

It seems both definitions work well for the usage in the news article.  What do native speakers think?

Comment: "over" five floors would be short for "spread over". 

Another example is "I served 5 customers over the course of 5 hours".

Comment: @Inazuma  So, the original was poorly written?

Comment: The original sounds totally fine.  That is a very, very common turn of phrase.  I understand it to have a word such as "spread or distributed elided: _The sprawling townhouse has 6,800 square feet of space_ [spread] _over five floors._

Comment: Adam is correct. Sorry for the lack of clarification.

Answer (score 1):

As a native speaker, it's absolutely fine. In this context, it uses Definition 9a.

It pretty much means:

> The sprawling townhouse has 6,800 square feet of space **shared among** five floors...